# Rendering both property value and property name of a JS object using .map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

Basically I need to render an object into a react component. It looks something like this:

```
var obj = {
  prop1: "prop1",
  prop2: "prop2",
  prop3: "prop3", 
}
```

I just want to print out both the property name and the value, and to do so I am using map, which currently looks something like this:

```
render(){
  return(
   <div>
    {Object.keys(obj).map(function(data, key){
      return (<div>{data}</div>);
    })}
   </div>
 );
}
```

The thing is, the way I have it, I am only able to render the property name, I have tried a few ways to access the property's value, but so far nothing works.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using the brackets notation**

Get the value using `obj[key]` (I've renamed `data` to `key`):

```
var obj = {
  prop1: "prop1",
  prop2: "prop2",
  prop3: "prop3", 
}

render(){
  return(
   <div>
    {Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){
      return (<div>{`${key}:${obj[key]}`}</div>);
    })}
   </div>
 );
}
```

**Using `Object#entries`**

[`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property [key, value] pairs. You can use it instead of `Object#keys`, and then iterated the results using `Array#map`. However, it's only supported by Chrome and FireFox.

```
var obj = {
  prop1: "prop1",
  prop2: "prop2",
  prop3: "prop3", 
}

render(){
  return(
   <div>
    {Object.entries(obj).map(function([key, value]){
      return (<div>{`${key}:${value}`}</div>);
    })}
   </div>
 );
}
```

Comment: Ohh my, clearly I've been working too much and didn't see the obvious.
Thanks!

Comment: @theJuls. Glad to help :) Try the `Object#entries` solution. It fits the problem better. There's also `Object#values`, but  it also lack in support.